# Cordova iOS libMobileGestalt Error App Fail to Load

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova

I recently upgraded my MacBook Pro to macOS Sierra 10.12.5 and XCode to 8.3.3.  When I try and launch my Cordova application, that worked in previous Xcode7 and previous macOS, it fails to fire deviceready.  The output below is all that I get.  Can someone please help me figure out why my app will no longer load?  Thanks!

```
2017-06-08 15:41:43.539333-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.3.1 is starting.
2017-06-08 15:41:43.539937-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2017-06-08 15:41:43.594456-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] Using UIWebView
2017-06-08 15:41:43.595559-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.060976ms
2017-06-08 15:41:43.596922-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.316011ms
2017-06-08 15:41:43.597009-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.046968ms
2017-06-08 15:41:43.597151-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] [CDVTimer][localnotification] 0.118971ms
2017-06-08 15:41:43.597184-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] [CDVTimer][localnotification] 0.004947ms
2017-06-08 15:41:43.606009-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 8.772969ms
2017-06-08 15:41:43.622880-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] [CDVTimer][file] 16.797006ms
2017-06-08 15:41:43.623421-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] Initializing MyPlugin
2017-06-08 15:41:43.623885-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] Initializing MyPlugin API
2017-06-08 15:41:43.625038-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] [CDVTimer][myplugin] 2.103984ms
2017-06-08 15:41:43.625443-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] [CDVTimer][localstorage] 0.369966ms
2017-06-08 15:41:43.625467-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 29.991031ms
2017-06-08 15:41:43.664677-0400 MyAppName[462:151027] libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 462 (MyAppName) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled
2017-06-08 15:41:43.664724-0400 MyAppName[462:151027] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see <rdar://problem/11744455>)
2017-06-08 15:41:43.814056-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2017-06-08 15:41:44.011163-0400 MyAppName[462:150991] Finished load of: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/470C218F-8E80-4218-B2BE-EFF60ACF43CF/MyAppName.app/www/index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this error message wasn't the cause of the problem.  I created a new iOS project in Cordova and re-added all my plugins and the app now fires device ready event.  This error message remains but at least the app is working as it did before.